# Fontconfig warning: ignoring UTF-8: not a valid region tag

Tags: 16.04, pdf

i am using the ubuntu 16.04.1 server, which is running on nginx. So whenever i try to generate the pdf. it throws following error : "Fontconfig warning: ignoring UTF-8: not a valid region tag" and my locale are as follows:

```
LANG=C.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

I have tried all other methods that had mentioned before. but it didn't solve any issue.How to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance